# Zend Navigation, how can i use it with params in the url ? I tried it with params in navigation without changes :(

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I have got a problem with the zend navigation.
I use the zend navigation, and its ok when i call something like this in the url:

```
www.website/article_new, www.website/article_list, 
www.website/friends_new, ...
```

But I want to call the site with some params like this:

```
www.website/article_new/123452/2335/45633246, 
www.website/friends_new/23453/3453524/34554
```

I try it about to set some params, but this doesnt function.

I put the navigation in the bootstrap and in the layout I use it. Its a Navigation with some breadcumps where display:true and display:false.
Here is a code from my bootstrap:

```
$navigation = new Zend_Navigation(array(
                                    array(
                                        'label' => 'Home',
                                        'controller' => 'index',
                                        'action' => 'index',
                                        'class' => 'menuF'
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'label' => 'Article',
                                        'controller' => 'Article_List',
                                        'id' => 'article',
                                        'action' => 'index',
                                        'class' => 'menu',
                                        'pages' => array(
                                            array(
                                            'label' => 'Neu',
                                            'id' => 'article',
                                            'controller' => 'Article_New',
                                            'action' => 'index',
                                            'class' => 'submenu'
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ).....
```

And the code from the layout.phtml. On this code I show if the breadcump is shown or not.

```
foreach($container as $page) {
                    $par = $active;
                    if ($page != $active && $page->getClass()!='menu' && $page->getClass()!='menuF' && $page->getID()!=$par->getID()) {
                        $page->setClass('submenu');

                    } else {
                        $found = $container->findAllBy('ID', $active->getID());
                        foreach($found AS $p){
                            if($p->getClass()!='menu'&&$p->getClass()!='menuF'){
                                $p->setClass('sub');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu($this->nav);
```

Hope anybody can help me! 
Thanks for all!
Best regards
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the mistake!

I want to call something like this:
www.website/article/344435/23452345

surely this throws a mistake, because there isnt any action like 344435

with something like this
www.website/article/show/var1/2435234/var2/2345234352
its ok.

the rest is something for routing!

Big sorry to all!
Greats Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the route name instead of the module, controler and action system.

```
array(
 'label' => 'Article',
 'route' => 'Article_List',
 'id' => 'article',
 'class' => 'menu',
 ...
)
```

The router will handle all the URL parsing and return the correct variables.